# Alinhar o "nav-item" para a direita, deixar centralizado

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

No meu navbar, eu tenho um botão de login, que queria alinhar para direita, float, align-items e text-align não funciona, como poderia fazer isso?

E quando não está logado (https://awme.herokuapp.com )[image: Alinhado]ele fica tudo alinhado, mas quando eu faço login com o discord, ele mostra o avatar e desalinha [image: Desalinhado]
A imagem está com 30x30

O código [html-jinja2] do meu navbar (cortando algumas partes) está assim:

```html
<header class="header ">
    <nav class="navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-dark">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/static/img/awme_logo.png?size=100" alt="Awme" title="Início"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler menu-i" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HeaderNavbar" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="HeaderNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/commands/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i> Comandos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i> Sobre</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/invite/" class="nav-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Convite</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item {% if logged %}dropdown{% endif %}">
                    {% if logged %}
                    <a href="#" id="user_dropdown" role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class='user-avatar' src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{{ user["id"] }}/{{ user["avatar"] }}.webp'> {{ user["username"] }}</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="user_dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/api/logout" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Deslogar</a>
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ login_url }}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Logar</a>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="head_sep"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kaigo faz o seguinte:

Primeiro tira o `li` que você quer que vá pra direita e coloca ele em uma `ul` separada. Depois adiciona `mr-auto` na class na primeira `ul`. O código vai ficar assim:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="HeaderNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/commands/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i> Comandos</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i> Sobre</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/invite/" class="nav-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Convite</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item {% if logged %}dropdown{% endif %}">
                {% if logged %}
                <a href="#" id="user_dropdown" role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class='user-avatar' src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{{ user["id"] }}/{{ user["avatar"] }}.webp'> {{ user["username"] }}</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="user_dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/api/logout" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Deslogar</a>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ login_url }}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Logar</a>
                {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Coloque a classe `w-100` e `align-items-center` na `ul.navbar-nav` para que o mesmo ocupe toda a largura da navbar e centralize os elementos verticalmente, e coloque a classe `ml-auto` na `li` que você quer alinhar à direita.

A classe `ml-auto` (`margin-left: auto`) irá aplicar uma margem esquerda automática ao elemento anterior fazendo com que a `li` fique alinhada no canto direito.

Adicione também duas classes no dropdown de login para alinhar à direita e dar uma margem do canto direito: `dropdown-menu-right` e `mr-4`:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mr-4 bg-dark" aria-labelledby="user_dropdown">
```

Coloque também a classe `pl-1` no link de deslogar para dar um padding esquerdo.

Adicione a @media query no seu CSS para ajustar os elementos quando a largura da tela for menor que 768px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){

   #HeaderNavbar > ul{
      align-items: flex-start !important;
   }

   #HeaderNavbar > ul li.ml-auto{
      margin-left: inherit !important;
   }

   #HeaderNavbar > ul li.ml-auto .mr-4{
      margin-right: inherit !important;
   }

}
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
body{
   background: black !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
   
   #HeaderNavbar > ul{
      align-items: flex-start !important;
   }

   #HeaderNavbar > ul li.ml-auto{
      margin-left: inherit !important;
   }

   #HeaderNavbar > ul li.ml-auto .mr-4{
      margin-right: inherit !important;
   }
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header class="header ">
    <nav class="navbar-expand-md navbar navbar-dark">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/static/img/awme_logo.png?size=100" alt="Awme" title="Início"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler menu-i" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#HeaderNavbar" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="HeaderNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 align-items-center">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/commands/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-terminal"></i> Comandos</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about/" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-robot"></i> Sobre</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/invite/" class="nav-link" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Convite</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
                  <a href="#" id="user_dropdown" role="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img class='user-avatar' src='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/dbd1337cc4d72037894eaf55e5c35752?s=40&d=mm&r=g'> {{ user["username"] }}</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right mr-4 bg-dark" aria-labelledby="user_dropdown">
                     <a class="nav-link pl-1" href="/api/logout" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Deslogar</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="head_sep"></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -3):

Estava com o mesmo problema, ao criar uma navbar com o código de exemplo do site
`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/`
os itens do menu ficavam a esquerda junto ao logo ou Brand, conforme mostrado no exemplo, porem queria os itens a direita.

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">`   
      `<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">`

Consegui resolver removendo:[ mb-2 mb-lg-0 ], o código ficou assim.

`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">`   
       `<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">`

Desta forma os itens do menu foram para direita